# EF Core save list of entities with navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm building an WebApi using .Net Core with EF Core (2.0) and found a problem when saving a list of entities.

The problem is that I have a navigation property in my entity, something like:

```
public class Student
{
    public Course Course {get; set;}
}
```

To save a single entity I'm using this to avoid trying to insert a Course that already exists:

```
student.Course = _context.Courses.Attach(student.Crouse).Entity
```

I find it ugly and would like to know a better way, but it works. Sometimes I allow the API to receive a list of `Students` and it should save them all. Calling `Attach` raises an exception if called twice on the same Course.

All I wanted was to EF Core to save only the Student entity with the correct foreign key, I want nothing done in the Course entity in the database. What is the best way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

> I find it ugly and would like to know a better way

Yes, there is [DTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5) . They are just like data models we create.

So, you will need to create a CreateStudentDto which you will use during creation.

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    //this won't contain the -> public Course Course {get; set;}
}
```

So, when you will get the input or map your input from entity class to createmodel, Mapper/Input will auto strip the Course from your create.